# In a graph, is it always possible to construct a set of cycle bases, with each and every edge Is shared by at most 2 cycle bases?

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph with a list of edges, is it possible to always construct a set of cycle bases for those edges, such that each and every edge is shared by at most 2 cycle bases?

The above question assumes that each and every edge must somehow belong to at least one cycle. IN other words, there is no vertex that is connected to one and only one edge.

Comment: Here's an extensive survey article on cycle bases: http://www.math.uga.edu/~caner/09vigre/SurveyCyclebases.pdf

Comment: And it cites a theorem of MacLane (1937) to the effect that a graph has such a cycle basis if and only if it is planar.

Comment: @BS, do you have a refernece on that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Lane%27s_planarity_criterion says: S. Mac Lane, A combinatorial condition for planar graphs, Fund. Math. 28 (1937), 22–32.

Comment: Additional reference.  Available online and shorter than the Mac Lane paper: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1973-037-02/S0002-9939-1973-0313098-X/S0002-9939-1973-0313098-X.pdf

Comment: Mac Lane's paper is also available online: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm28/fm2814.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the complete graph on 7 vertices. It has 21 edges, so any set of cycles that utilizes each edge at most twice has size at most 42/3=14. But the cycle space of the graph has dimension 21-7+1=15, so you cannot have a basis with the requested property.

Comment: I don't follow your logic, is there any nonintuitive properties of graphs and edges that you make use of when you make this deduction?

Comment: I implicitly use that all cycles contain at least 3 edges, and that the dimension of the cycle space is the number of edges exceeding that of a tree with the same vertices. Both facts are straightforward, could you please elaborate on where exactly you have problems?

Comment: Thorny, first are you saying that you assume a graph with 7 vertices and 21 edges? If yes, then your reasoning at most hold for that case, what about other case? Second, how do you actually define *dimension of the cycle base*?

Comment: I answer the question "In a graph, is it always possible to construct a set of cycle bases, with each and every edge Is shared by at most 2 cycle bases?" in the negative, so one counterexample is all it takes. If you wanted to ask a more precise question, then BS's lead is what you should read. As for your other question, please consult http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_space .

Comment: @Thorny, I *still* don't quite follow your logic. If you may, you might want to construct a diagram that answers my question negatively in graphical terms, that would be tremendously helpful. Sorry and thanks a lot!

Comment: To answer "is it always possible to construct a set of cycle bases with each and every edge shared by at most 2 bases?" in the negative, I construct a graph for which no such cycle base exists. The example I give is the complete graph on 7 vertices. In it, the cycle space (see above) has dimension #edges-#vertices+1=21-7+1=15. No matter how you select 15 nonempty cycles or unions of cycles, those will have at least 45 edges counted with multiplicity. This is more than twice the number of edges in the graph, so by the pigeonhole principle at least one edge will be used 3 times or more.

Comment: @Thorny: Which kind of [cycle space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_space) are you talking about?

Comment: @Casebash: the binary one.

Comment: I think I manage to understand this argument, thanks. 